# Getting the selected value of a listbox in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, listbox

In my ascx, I have a listbox control defined as:

```
<asp:ListBox id="Listbox1" rows="1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="btn_click" />
```

In my ascx.cs, I populate the listbox with:

```
Listbox1.Items.Add(new ListItem("textVar", "valueVar"));
```

I'm trying to read the selected value with:

```
label1.Text = Listbox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

But this results in an empty string in Label1.Text.  Any ideas?  I'm still new to .NET and C#, so I apologize if this is rudimentary.  Seems like it ought to a simple thing  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your label text being set to the selected value inside of the btn_click event handler?

Comment: Did you wrap the population of the listbox in a `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` ?

Comment: Sorry, I finally figured it out.  Coding is correct, had a problem with my Page_Load function.  Sorry for the false alarm.

Comment: I you solved the problem, please answer to your own question and mark it as the answser. This will help future readers to see that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Any ideas?

Yes, i assume that you are databinding the `ListBox` on every postback. Do that only  `if(!IsPostBack)`, otherwise the `SelectedIndexChanged` will not be triggered.

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        Listbox1.Items.Clear();
        Listbox1.Items.Add(new ListItem("textVar", "valueVar"));
    }
}
```